# Big o notation for nested loops with an inner loop that depends on the outer loop

Tags: big-o

I'm just learning big O notation and I'm confused about nested loops:

```
for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
   for (int y = 0; y < n; y++)
      for (int z = 0; z < y; z++)
         anything();
```

From my understanding the inner loop above executes n(n+1)/2 times, the second loop executes n times and the first loop executes n times. Shouldn't this mean the big O is n x n x n(n+1)/2 = O(n^4)? Why doesn't the second loop get included in the big O formulation?

Comment: n(n+1)/2 is the number of times the code inside the innermost loop executes _per run of the middle loop_, so when you're getting n x n x n(n+1)/2, you're counting the middle loop twice.

Answer (score 1):

The question is: how often does `anything()` get called, as a function of `n`?

> the inner loop above executes n(n+1)/2 times

No, the inner loop executes y times (*per times you enter it*), and y averages n/2.

So the equation is n * n * n/2 = O(n^3).

Answer (score 0):

Big O notation is to express the upperbound of the algorithm. So, if a loop based algorithm is running n²+n times, we still say in big O notation as O(n²).
Refer this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-big-o-notation-820d2e25d3fd) for a more detailed explanation.